# How to make a unit test for this method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a database with users and their friends, and then I have this task to retrieve the friends:

```
public async Task<List<User>> RetrieveFriends(int id)
{
    var user = await _userDbContext.Users.FindAsync(id);
    var friends = user.Friends;
    return (List<User>)friends;
}
```

How can I make a unit test for this? (just a unit test, not integration test or anything similar).

Comment: You can't. All functionality is related to retrieving from the database. If you mock that, you'll be testing absolutely nothing. A lot of people do it, but it makes no sense. Make an integration test or don't test it at all.

Comment: I agree with @PalleDue. This method is nearly impossible to test (meaningful). BUT: You should be sure about the expectations of that method. I think it will work fine if the user is present in the database - but what should happen if it's not present? `FirstAsync` should throw an exception if the user could not be found. If this is not intended you should change your implementation maybe to return an empty array like `return (await _userDbContext.Users.FindOrDefaultAsync(id))?.Friends as IList<User> ?? Array.Empty<User>();` The return type should be `IList<User>` in that case.

Comment: There's no logic in this method, so there's nothing to test here. 
However, I would like to point out that it might break if `FindAsync` returns null when the relevant user is not found in the datacase.

Comment: I believe it depends on what class this method is a part of. Because if `RetrieveFriends` is a part of your DB repository interface implementation then I would agree with the rest of the comments and say that testing it it's not that necessary.

But if that's not the case and, for instance, `RetrieveFriends` is the controller of an endpoint of your application that allows getting a user's friends then I'd say that there's plenty of business logic here; and you would be delegating it to your ORM which is not a very nice decision from an architectural standpoint :)

Comment: You could mock `_usersDbContext.Users.FindAsync(id)` and test what happens to your method on the edge cases. For example, try returning `null`, an empty array, an array of users that have missing fields, that have null fields, etc.. This would uncover errors like the one pointed out by @ZoharPeled